# complex select query for mysql combining two column with where clause

Tags: mysql, select, join

i have two tables like

**TABLE 1 : FACULTY_DETAILS**

**fac_det_id**(pk)........**fname**...........**availability**

.....1......................... xxx.................full time

.....2......................... yyy.................part time

.....3......................... zzz.................weekdays

.....4......................... aaa.................partime

**TABLE 2: FACULTY**

**faculty_id**(pk)..........**course_id**........**fac_det_id**(fk)

.....1..............................1......................2

.....2..............................2......................3

.....3..............................3......................1

.....4..............................4......................3

.....5..............................3......................4

when i give course id
i need fname ,availability in table1 and faculty_id in table 2

ie if i give course_id=3 then i need like

**faculty_id**..........**fname**...........**qualification**

.....2...................xxx................full time

.....5...................aaa................partime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
SELECT faculty_id, fname, availibility AS qualification
FROM faculty a, faculty_details b
WHERE a.fac_det_id = b.fac_det_id AND course_id = $your_course_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT f.faculty_id, fd.fname, fd.availability  qualification 
FROM FACULTY f 
INNER JOIN FACULTY_DETAILS fd ON f.fac_det_id = fd.fac_det_id 
WHERE f.course_id = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
select f.faculty_id,fd.fname,fd.availability as qualification
from faculty f,faculty_details fd
inner join  faculty_details fd ON f.fac_det_id = fd.fac_det_id 
where course_id=3;
```